# how to validate whether a specific email exist in the firebase database and how to fetch it for log in validation

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Actually I have created a registration form but having a little logical problem in the login page. In the log-in page whenever a user enters data and presses the submit button he/she should be directed to their specific page by validating whether that specific email entered on the input fields is present in the firebase.

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Contact Form</h2>
            <div class="alert alert-success success-message" style="display:none;">Form submitted successfully.</div>
            <form id="contactForm">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleEmail">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control email" id="exampleEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleEmail">password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control email" id="examplePass" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <div id ="data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script>
var email, password ;
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "AIzaSyDTMz1qgSStS6b6NLkikEVDeI-ZTkCLyEM",
          authDomain: "venderapp-c42cf.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://venderapp-c42cf.firebaseio.com",
          projectId: "venderapp-c42cf",
          storageBucket: "venderapp-c42cf.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "882847151210",
          appId: "1:882847151210:web:6b7392dbc76b437386c613"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      $('#contactForm').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
             email=document.getElementById("exampleEmail").value;
          password=document.getElementById("examplePass").value;
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {

      console.log("logged in");
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
    });
    // ...
  });

      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        console.log(user);
        if(user) {
        console.log(user);
        }
      });

    </script>
```

Comment: "validating whether that specific email ... is present in the firebase." Can you elaborate on what Firebase product you want to check for the presence of the email address?

Comment: Actually sorry but I don't get your question properly .but I want to do it on real time firebase database.. .is that you wanted ?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Keep in mind that Firebase Authentication users are not automatically inserted into the database. Your code shows no interaction with the database, so as a result of this code there will be no users in the database. If you want to store the users in the database, you should write the code for that. I recommend doing a few searches on the site here, as that has been covered quite well already. If you then want to search the database, a search is also a good way to find what folks have done before.

Comment: [javascript store additional user info in firebase](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+store+additional+user+info+in+firebase) and [javascript query user name exists](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+query+user+name+exists)

Comment: Actually I have written code to read and write the data into database in another HTML file.but in this file I just want to validate the user.

Comment: Cool. That means you're halfway there. The links in the second search I gave you will show you how to query the database for a specific value. If you're having trouble making that work for your database, edit the question to show what you've tried. I highly recommend studing [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it's the best way to maximize the chances that someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem when I was developing an Android app with Java. I could authenticate users with the Firebase Authentication SDK but was unable to check if the user existed in the database, and frankly they DO NOT exist in the database unless you explicitly write it there.

So what I did was as soon as the user's email was validated, say using Google Login or Facebook Login, I would retrieve the current user's email or user token and save it inside `Users` node. Firebase Realtime Database allows data querying, which was quite fast for the Free plan, so I guess it's ok doing so.

Sad to say the authentication part does not automatically save users data in the database. Unless the whole authentication system is based on the Firebase Realtime Database instead of something else.